# Protect controller functions with session values in a extra function

Tags: node.js, express

I have some session values that describes if a user is an admin or not. currently I do something like this:

```
exports.DeleteUser = function (req, res) {
    if(req.session == undefined || req.session.Lv < 80){
        res.render("Login");
        return;
    }

    //Code
    res.render(...);
}
```

So if someone want to access the page and no session values or if the session value "Lv" is less than 80 the user would get to the login.

I have ~20 controller functions and writing that code block 20 times seems a bit to much.

What would be a efficient way to write this in a function? The only way I see would be a function with a return value true or false but then I still need an if with the "return" in it with would makes this only 1 row shorter.. Or can this be done Controller wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## You can solve this issue following way :

```
// Session or valid user checker
// middleware function
// file : sessionChecker.js 
const sessionChecker = (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.session == undefined || req.session.Lv < 80){
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
};
module.exports = sessionChecker;
```

#### Router

```
const sessionChecker = require('./sessionChecker.js');
const blogController = require('./blogController.js');
const userController = require('./userController.js');

// use sessionChecker middleware for check session
router.get('/blogs', sessionChecker, blogController.index);
router.get('/users', sessionChecker, userController.index);
```

#### Controller

```
// File : blogController.js

const BlogController  = module.exports = {
    /**
     * Index method
     * @param req
     * @param res
     * @return {Promise<void>}
     */
    index: async (req, res) => {
        let data = {
            pageTitle: "Blog Lists",
            blogs : await blogRepo.get(req, res),
        };

        res.render('home', data);
    }
}
```